# big POST Data is cut (XMLRPC call)

Tags: php, linux, apache, command-line-interface, xml-rpc

I am trying to call an external server via xml-rpc of zendframework and take the xml data from there.

my application is a console application but the request is working with http POST and the string i am getting is cut when the number of characters are "2097152" and even though the server is sending a much bigger string on this side I can not get more than that.

I have increased "memory_limit", "post_max_size" and all other variables in php.ini of cli and apache but nothing have been changes.

I'm using php 7.0.4 and Ubuntu 16.04 (but this happened with PHP5 and Ubuntu 14 also in another server.)

the sending server cannot be the problem because with other receivers like a xmlrpc chrome extension, I am getting all 15,000 entities of my views back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the "keepalive" in the HTTP Post Client to TRUE and everything works like a charm!